# Linker error: undefined reference to `fstat'

Tags: qt, linker-errors

I am getting below linker errors while building Qt for embedded ARM linux platform, Any ideas what can be the reason? or How to solve it?

> .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qtconcurrentiteratekernel.o: In function
>   `getticks()': qtconcurrentiteratekernel.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined
>   reference to`clock_gettime'
>   .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qthread_unix.o: In function
>   `set_thread_data(QThreadData*)': qthread_unix.cpp:(.text+0x40):
>   undefined reference to`__tls_get_addr'
>   .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qthread_unix.o: In function
>   `QThreadData::current()': qthread_unix.cpp:(.text+0x37c): undefined
>   reference to`__tls_get_addr' .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qresource.o:
>   In function `QDynamicFileResourceRoot::registerSelf(QString const&)':
>   qresource.cpp:(.text._ZN24QDynamicFileResourceRoot12registerSelfERK7QString[QDynamicFileResourceRoot::registerSelf(QString
>   const&)]+0x88): undefined reference to`fstat'
>   .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qfilesystemengine.o: In function
>   `QFileSystemEngine::fillMetaData(int, QFileSystemMetaData&)':
>   qfilesystemengine.cpp:(.text+0x490): undefined reference to`fstat'
>   .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qfilesystemengine_unix.o: In function
>   `QFileSystemEngine::currentPath()':
>   qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to`stat'
>   .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qfilesystemengine_unix.o: In function
>   `QFileSystemEngine::removeDirectory(QFileSystemEntry const&, bool)':
>   qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp:(.text+0x3bc): undefined reference to`
>   stat' .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qfilesystemengine_unix.o: In
>   function `QFileSystemEngine::createDirectory(QFileSystemEntry const&,
>   bool)': qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp:(.text+0x5c4): undefined reference
>   to`stat' .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qfilesystemengine_unix.o: In
>   function `QFileSystemEngine::fillMetaData(QFileSystemEntry const&,
>   QFileSystemMetaData&, QFlags<QFileSystemMetaData::MetaDataFlag>)':
>   qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp:(.text+0xda4): undefined reference to`
>   lstat' qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp:(.text+0xe34): undefined reference
>   to `stat' .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qtranslator.o: In function`
>   QTranslatorPrivate::do_load(QString const&)':
>   qtranslator.cpp:(.text+0x1730): undefined reference to `fstat'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: ***
>   [../../lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.0] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's something wrong with your toolchain or qmake.conf. Try to manually link to libc and to rt library either in your qmake.conf or in the configure using -l and -L: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/configure-options.html.